# Setting shortcuts for newly created actions in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on a painter-like application which allows user to draw points on an image and manage them using different subsets of points. Subsets are created upon triggering an action. Newly created subsets are also actions and they are numbered from 1 to how much user needs. I want to set shortcuts for newly created actions upon creating. For example, for action "Set_2" i want a shortcut "Ctrl+2", for "Set_3"- "Ctrl+3", etc.
Here's piece of code which shows how actions are created in my application:

```
void ImageViewer::on_New_setAct_triggered()
{
    setnumber++;
    newset = new QAction;
    newset->setText(QString("Set_" + QString::number(setnumber)));

   /...
}
```

Any idea on possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QAction` class has a [`setShortcut()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#shortcut-prop) method that takes as a parameter a [`QKeySequence`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequence.html):

> Valid keycodes for this property can be found in [Qt::Key](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#Key-enum) and [Qt::Modifier](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#Modifier-enum).

```
QAction *newset = new QAction();
newset->setShortcut(QKeySequence(tr("Ctrl+%1").arg(setnumber)));
```